# Passing JavaScript value into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a form, when the user fill the location, it will show the map route and route distance. I want to pass the distance into my PHP variable but I don't know how to do it. Can we pass the JS variable value into JSON and extract it into a PHP variable? If can help me or if there is alternative method(s) please tell me.

Comment: Pass the variable into a hidden input element and send across with the post data.

Comment: use ajax to send POST or GET request to a backend php script which can then read that request and process accordingly

Comment: i use window.location.href  to pass js variable into php and it works but another problem is . the web page reload continously.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
     url:"ajax.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{distance:distance},
     success:function(data){
        if(data){
            then do something
        }
     }
});
</script>
```

In `ajax.php` you can get it as below.

```
<?php
    $distance = $_REQUEST['distance'];
?>
```

If you array of values you can do as below.

```
<script>
dataArray[] = {1000,2000,3000}
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
jQuery.ajax({
     url:"ajax.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{distance:jsonString},
     success:function(data){
        if(data){
            then do something
        }
     }
});
</script>
```

In `ajax.php` you can easily get the request data.

```
<?php
    $distance = $_REQUEST['distance'];
    foreach($distance as $dist){


    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a badly formatted mess that is full of syntax errors and bad practises. The question isn't tagged jQuery either.